# Unity Raycast Warning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have a Raycasting script, which works, but I keep getting this warning: [My VSCommunity Warning Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxOLi.png) Line 5: `[SerializeField] Camera camera;` I don't think the warning is a major problem, but I still want to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
public class RaycastCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    Camera camera;
    GameObject raycastHitGameObject;


    public GameObject GetRaycastHitGameObject()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            raycastHitGameObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
        }

        return raycastHitGameObject;
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply stating that somewhere in your inheritance chain, a class variable named `camera` is already declared.

You can hide the already declared variable by using the `new` keyword.

```
new Camera camera;
```